# invalid_grant error with accession Office365 Outlook OAuth

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, office365, office365api, office365-apps

GETTING ERROR

> {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '987bdee9-c048-4ea0-b056-25ffc88d536c' named 'Linwood Homes Outlook'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: 9cecffb0-cf4f-43f1-b28e-4289b1fa0700\r\nCorrelation ID: 5c6e6d7a-ffec-463b-96ab-dac53bc5c383\r\nTimestamp: 2018-07-20 10:23:06Z","error_codes":[65001],"timestamp":"2018-07-20 10:23:06Z","trace_id":"9cecffb0-cf4f-43f1-b28e-4289b1fa0700","correlation_id":"5c6e6d7a-ffec-463b-96ab-dac53bc5c383","suberror":"consent_required"}

I am using Office365 outlook REST API to Send and Receive new emails in our application.

Comment: Could you post the actual input request in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to add admin consent. I had to login with global admin account and then in Scope section, Added added scope permissions for all users.

Thanks!